Firebase realtimeDB serverTimestamp to synchronise clients at ms accuracy
I am trying to synchronise multiple clients to trigger a time sensitive event at the exact same time using firebase realtime database.
One client sets the serverTimestamp into a document, and all others use it to calculate when to trigger the event based on this "server" timestamp.
Problem: serverTimestamp is different when read on each client, with a difference of several hundred milliseconds. This is true for 2 browsers running on the same machine - so its not UTC time diff.
My first guess was that firebase is adding delay offsets (latency), but when i print .info/serverTimeOffset on each client, its comparatively very small, and always positive as it should be.
right now, its more accurate to use the sender client's UTC time rather than this serverTimestamp.
So my question is, why is serverTimestamp is a different number when read on each client.


My first guess was that firebase is adding delay offsets (latency), but when i print .info/serverTimeOffset on each client, its comparatively very small, and always positive as it should be.

This is correct.  The client has no way to be 100% perfectly in sync with the backend because of the network latency between the client and server.  This latency is going to be different for each client, depending on network conditions, and even those conditions can change over time.
Futhermore, you can't assume that any client's internal clock is going to be the same as Firebase.  The client's operating system likely has its own synchronization method (using some other source) that makes a similar estimate, but it will never be 100% accurate.
Maybe some day we will all get atomic clocks in our devices to minimize time differences, but until that happens, we have to allow systems to guess the latency.
